# To display the color list horizontally instead vertically using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a lit of colors that are currently displayed vertically, however i need something to spread out the color list width wise as and when they are added to the list. below are the screenshot:

Vertical List

[image]

that I need to make it look like:

[image]

In short its good to have 3-4 colors per row. How can achieve this in css?

The code is react: and below is the css.

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div styleName={main}>
          <DropDownButton>
              {this.mapItems(colors)}
          </DropDownButton>
        </div>
    );
  }
 createListItem(color) {
        return (
            <a href="#" styleName={colorAll}>
              <span style={{background:"#"+color}} styleName={spanStyle}>

              </span>
            </a>
        )
      }

      mapItems(colors) {
        return colors.map(this.createListItem.bind(this));
      }
```

css:

```
.main {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
.spanStyle {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  &:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.colorAll {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: could you show us your CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to parent container this properies:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction:row:
flex-wrap:wrap:
```

And add to child elements if you want 3 element per row : `flex-basis: 33%` or if you want 4 elements per `row flex-basis:25%`. Read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, just change the value for `height` in `.main`:

```
.main {
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
```

or try pixel values for height:

```
.main {
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: i tried that, it only hide the remaining content , but does not cause it to spread widely

Comment: some more code would be necessary to tell you more, like what is happening around tose elements (HTML and CSS)

Comment: It seems there is an additional element between `.main` and `.spanStyle` which affects the display - for example: there's a blue border to the right and below these squares in your image, which is definitely not caused by anything you posted...